# How to open urls through submit of a form with checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a form with some checkboxes. To each checkbox is bundled an url. User checks one or more checkboxes, press `submit` and urls of checked checkboxes open in new tabs.

I tried a snippet, which illustrates my idea, but without success:

```
<form>

    <label for="cb1">G</label>
    <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" onSubmit="window.open('http://google.com/','_blank')">

    <label for="cb2">Y</label>
    <input id="cb2" type="checkbox" onSubmit="window.open('http://yahoo.com/','_blank')">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**PS**:

I nearly achieved my goal with

```
<script>

  function checkForm(form)
  {
    if(form.cb1.checked) {
window.open('http://google.com/','_blank');
    }
        if(form.cb2.checked) {
window.open('http://yahoo.com/','_blank');
    }

    return true;
  }

</script>

<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">

    <label for="cb1">G</label>
    <input name="cb1" type="checkbox">

    <label for="cb2">Y</label>
    <input name="cb2" type="checkbox">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**What i need**: how can i correctly separate HTML from Javascript? This code will be used in a Chrome extension, and there is the construction `<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">` not allowed.

So i want to have pure HTML in the popup.html and Javascript in popup.js

Comment: AFAIK, input does not have submit event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in JavaScript:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
const checkboxOne = document.getElementById("cb1")
const checkboxTwo = document.getElementById("cb2")

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (checkboxOne.checked && checkboxTwo.checked) {
    //for open two tabs it is necessary to allow pop up or use chrome "api"
    window.open("http://google.com/");
    window.open("http://yahoo.com/");
  } else if (checkboxOne.checked) {
    window.open("http://google.com/");
  } else if(checkboxTwo.checked){
    window.open("http://yahoo.com/");
  }

});
```

```html
<label for="cb1">G</label>
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox">

<label for="cb2">Y</label>
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```